# Ubuntu 14.04 wired connection not detecting

Tags: networking, ubuntu-14.04

[image][image]I dual booted Windows with Ubuntu a few weeks back. My Internet connection seems to be automatically detected on Windows, but not on Ubuntu.

Here is the output from `ifconfig`:

```
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:17:7c:19:32:8d
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1 RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0 inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1 RX packets:175 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 TX packets:175 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 RX bytes:12609 (12.6 KB) TX bytes:12609 (12.6 KB)
```

**REVISED** Current:
This is everything in the /etc/network/interfaces file

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8) 
auto lo eth0 
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

btw i have no connections added wen i checked my network preferences

Comment: What does your "/etc/network/interfaces" have? is it dhcp?

Comment: Do you have a gui? What does Network Manager display? It should have an Auto eth0 line with Connect automatically and Available to everyone checkboxes. Display screen if you can.

Answer (score 3):

Check or Set network interface to DHCP:
Open file in a text editor as root:

> sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces

Check the eth0 lines in the file:

> auto eth0
>
> iface eth0 inet dhcp

Save the file and exit.

Restart the network:

> sudo service network-manager restart

**DEFAULT** settings for eth0 with dhcp:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Comment: hey i changed it to
"auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp"
and restarted it too... 
it was loopback instead of dhcp earlier but it still seems no different...btw i edited the original file...is there a way to reset to the default settings?

Comment: @mrdoubtful Added the default settings for the network interface.

Comment: I changed it to dhcp and restarted but i'm still disconnected.
This is the /etc/network/interfaces file...

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet dhcp

Comment: @mrdoubtful Can you post file above? everything in the /etc/network/interfaces file...

Comment: is that a typo in your comment? "auto lo iface lo inet dhcp" should be "auto lo eth0 iface eth0 inet dhcp". Everything I posted as default is everything you need if you have one network adapter.

Comment: Wel actually I left tat out...I have posted the file btw

Comment: you should have modified your original question and not added it as an answer which it is not. I moved the content.

Comment: Hope the screenshots help...

Comment: I had to edit  /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and I've changed managed=false to managed=true